# Full Outer Join for Access with Nested Joins

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, nested-loops, dao

I'm attempting a Full Outer Join workaround for Access. My code currently works with one table but when I attempt to nest additional left/right joins, I get an "3075 Syntax Error." I believe Access wants me to put quotes or parenthesis somewhere but I've tried several different ways and researched and can't seem to grasp it. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

```
SQL = ""
SQL = SQL & "SELECT "
SQL = SQL & "          t.* "
SQL = SQL & "FROM "
SQL = SQL & "          ( "
SQL = SQL & "                    SELECT "
SQL = SQL & "                              [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB] "
SQL = SQL & "                            , [SummaryTbl].[PROGRAM] "
SQL = SQL & "                            , [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_TYPE] "
SQL = SQL & "                            , [ParentChildTbl].[HasAssocWI] "
SQL = SQL & "                    FROM "
SQL = SQL & "                              SummaryTbl "
SQL = SQL & "                              LEFT JOIN "
SQL = SQL & "                                        ParentChildTbl "
SQL = SQL & "                              ON "
SQL = SQL & "                                        [SummaryTbl]. 
[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = [ParentChildTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB] "
SQL = SQL & "                              LEFT JOIN "
SQL = SQL & "                                        ObjectsAffectedTbl "
SQL = SQL & "                              ON "
SQL = SQL & "                                        [SummaryTbl]. 
[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = [ObjectsAffectedTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB] "
SQL = SQL & "                     "
SQL = SQL & "                    UNION "
SQL = SQL & "                     "
SQL = SQL & "                    SELECT "
SQL = SQL & "                              [ParentChildTbl]. 
[WORK_ITEM_NMB] "
SQL = SQL & "                            , [SummaryTbl].[PROGRAM] "
SQL = SQL & "                            , [SummaryTbl].[WORK_ITEM_TYPE] "
SQL = SQL & "                            , [ParentChildTbl].[HasAssocWI] "
SQL = SQL & "                    FROM "
SQL = SQL & "                              SummaryTbl "
SQL = SQL & "                              RIGHT JOIN "
SQL = SQL & "                                        ParentChildTbl "
SQL = SQL & "                              ON "
SQL = SQL & "                                        [SummaryTbl]. 
[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = [ParentChildTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB] "
SQL = SQL & "                              RIGHT JOIN "
SQL = SQL & "                                        ObjectsAffectedTbl "
SQL = SQL & "                              ON "
SQL = SQL & "                                        [SummaryTbl]. 
[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = [ObjectsAffectedTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB] "
SQL = SQL & "          ) "
SQL = SQL & "          t "
SQL = SQL & "   WHERE "
SQL = SQL & "          t.[WORK_ITEM_NMB] > 700"

 Updated: 
 I added parenthesis as follows: 
SQL = SQL & "                    FROM "
SQL = SQL & "                              (SummaryTbl "
SQL = SQL & "                              RIGHT JOIN "
SQL = SQL & "                                        ParentChildTbl "
SQL = SQL & "                              ON "
SQL = SQL & "                                        [SummaryTbl]. 
[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = [ParentChildTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB]) "
SQL = SQL & "                              RIGHT JOIN "
SQL = SQL & "                                        ParentChildTbl "
SQL = SQL & "                              ON "
SQL = SQL & "                                        [ParentChildTbl]. 
[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = [ObjectsAffectedTbl].[WORK_ITEM_NMB]) "
SQL = SQL & "          ) "
```

I think these are in the correct place now because now I'm getting the error in the `Union` clause instead of the From clause. But I'm not sure what to do with the `Union` clause now.

Comment: In Access, for any complex query beyond returning columns, one should use saved queries (which engine caches best execution plan) and not VBA string queries run on the fly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that option. I did add parenthesis and I think it's in the correct place because now it's telling me the Union clause has an error instead of the From clause.

Comment: I do not understand. So you do not have the software, MSACCESS.EXE? You can still create stored queries in code.

Comment: I have to work off an existing read-only database.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access SQL, more than one `JOIN` requires parentheses pairings. Below also uses table aliases for concision and readability:

```
SELECT
          t.*
FROM
          (
                    SELECT
                              s.[WORK_ITEM_NMB]
                            , s.[PROGRAM]
                            , s.[WORK_ITEM_TYPE]
                            , p.[HasAssocWI]
                    FROM
                            (
                             (SummaryTbl s
                              LEFT JOIN
                                        ParentChildTbl p
                              ON
                                        s.[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = p.[WORK_ITEM_NMB]
                             )
                              LEFT JOIN
                                        ObjectsAffectedTbl o
                              ON
                                        s.[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = o.[WORK_ITEM_NMB]
                             )

                    UNION

                    SELECT
                              p.[WORK_ITEM_NMB]
                            , s.[PROGRAM]
                            , s.[WORK_ITEM_TYPE]
                            , p.[HasAssocWI]
                    FROM
                            (
                             (ObjectsAffectedTbl o
                              LEFT JOIN
                                        ParentChildTbl p
                              ON
                                        o.[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = p.[WORK_ITEM_NMB]
                             )
                              LEFT JOIN
                                        SummaryTbl s
                              ON
                                        o.[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = s.[WORK_ITEM_NMB]
                             )
          ) t
   WHERE
          t.[WORK_ITEM_NMB] > 700
```

By the way, consider saving above in a .sql (i.e., text file) and read into a VBA string to avoid concatenation and quote handling:

```vb
Function ReadSQL() As String
    Dim LoadFileStr As String

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
          LoadFileStr = .OpenTextFile("C:\Path\To\File.sql", 1).readall
    End With

    ReadSQL = LoadFileStr
End Sub

Sub mySub 
   ...
   SQL = ReadSQL()
   ...
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm now getting a 3296 = Join expression not supported error with your code. I think I need to join table o. to p. not just s., maybe?

Comment: I added another left and right join like so:                                                            
SQL = SQL & "                               Left Join"
SQL = SQL & "                                         ObjectsAffectedTbl o"
SQL = SQL & "                               ON"
SQL = SQL & "                                        p.[WORK_ITEM_NMB] = o.[WORK_ITEM_NMB]"
SQL = SQL & "                              )"                                                                     
and now I'm getting error 3319 again for the union query.

Comment: Usually the `LEFT JOIN` is easier to read in SQL. See adjustment of reversing table order and replacing `RIGHT JOIN`.